# Debugging VGA signal

Tags: oscilloscope, vga, logic-analyzer

I have tried to use my Open bench logic sniffer to capture data from a VGA output.

I'm pretty sure I understand how the waveform should look, but I not getting consistent data. It feels very shaky to be honest.

I heard somewhere that you must have a sampling rate that is 10x the signal frequency to have enough resolution, so 640x480 VGA is clocked at 25 MHz and OLS has a maximum sampling rate of 200 MHz. Could that explain the situation?

Can anyone

A) recommend something a step-up from OLS and

B) weigh in on the issue. Are my conclusions right or are there operational problems from my side with the hardware/software at hand ?

Comment: The sample rate is fine, but do you understand that VGA is an *analog* signal, not a digital signal (well, except for the sync pulses)? Does OLS digitize analog signals? Based on a [quick look](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Open_Bench_Logic_Sniffer), it would seem not.

Comment: Yes, Im aware of VGA being analog :) Im debugging a hsync issue that failed to reveal itself due even if I enable compression. I've done some research today and I think a Picoscope 3200 series is the cure to the problem.

Comment: HSync has a frequency in the kHZ, so it's easy to observe. Unless of course your problem is short glitches, short enough to confuse the monitor.

Also, one lesson I learned last year: are your sync signals at proper levels? Some monitors don't care. Others are very particular, and I encountered one that ignored my sync pulses because they were 3.3V, not 5V. (I was only experimenting, and didn't care to level shift yet)